# nodejs at heroku craches the Dyno

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a simple server app called server.js.

It works great on my local machine, but I have the following problem when I deploy it to heroku:

The root folder contains:

1. server.js
2. package.json
3. Procfile:
   `web: node server.js`

I have created a new heroku account and pushed to it this simple root folder

when executing `heroku ps`

I am getting:

`=== web (1X): node server.js
web.1: crashed 2014/03/26 16:21:32 (~ 4m ago)`

What can be the problem??

Thanks,
Guy.

Comment: running `heroku ps:scale web=1`, seems to be working fine.. but still the dyno in crashed

Comment: After scaling, did you restart the dyno?

Comment: running `heroku restart web.1` yields this: `Restarting web.1 dyno... failed! No app specified.`

Comment: You need to restart your app like this: `heroku restart --app` followed by your app name. SO if your app name is "unicorn-bandit.herokuapp.com", then you give your command like: `heroku restart --app unicorn-bandit`

Comment: restarted with given name at the name sction in the package.json. Still have a problem `Restarting dynos... failed! App not found` :(

Comment: `App not found` - It means you provided an incorrect app name. Do you have the app name with you or are you creating / pushing to heroku for the first time and have not yet created the app?

Comment: I am pushing to heroku for the first time.. maybe there is a problem in the push process?

Comment: Can you check if you have carried out the steps as mentioned in this documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Comment: yep.. I have followed all the steps in this guide.